# in mongodb when submitted form collections are empty. not getting any data into it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

in mongodb when submitted form I m getting empty collections not getting any data into it. according to my post request I am neither getting item is saved nor any error only empty after clicking the submit button. only ContactDance database with empty collections are being made by the name of Contacts(collection name).my code is right here.

```
const fs=require("fs");

const express=require("express");

const path=require("path");

const app=express();

app.use(express.json());

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyparser=require("body-parser");


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/ContactDance", {useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true});

const port=80;

const ContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email:String,
  number:String,
  address:String,
  city:String,

});
const Contact = mongoose.model("Contact", ContactSchema);

app.use("/static",express.static("static"));
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.set("view engine","pug");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname,"views"));



app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
  res.status(200).render("home.pug");
})
app.get("/contact",(req,res)=>{
  const params={ }
  res.status(200).render("contact.pug",params);
})




app.post("/contact",(req,res)=>{
  var myData=new Contact(req.body);
  myData.save().then(()=>{
    res.send("this item has been saved");
  }).catch(()=>{
    res.status(400).send("item is not saved");
  })
  
})

 

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`server is running on ${port}`)
});
``
```

Comment: Are you sure you have used the `body-parser` correctly (see [Express body-parser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

Add this line and ignore the deprecated error if you face.